# Powershell Error: "There is not enough memory or disk to complete the operation"

Tags: powershell, disk

I'm running a powershell script to read multiple word documents. When running to around 700 documents, it shows error "There is not enough memory or disk to complete the operation".
Here is my code

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.application
$source = 'powershell/attachments'
$docs = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Filter *cover*.docx


$XL = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
#Open the workbook
$WB = $XL.Workbooks.Open("powershell/result.xlsx")
#Activate Sheet1, pipe to Out-Null to avoid 'True' output to screen
$WB.Sheets.Item("Sheet1").Activate() | Out-Null
$SearchArray = @('employment', 'source of income', 'US address', 'residential address', 'ID', 'driver license', 'visa', 'passport', 'I-20', 'Social Security Card', 'information update form', 'w9', 'w8', 'tax', 'email address')
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.application

foreach ($doc in $docs) {
    $Document = $word.Documents.Open($doc)
    $CVSInfo = $Document.Paragraphs | ForEach-Object{
        foreach ($SerchText in $SearchArray) {
            $_.Range.Text | Where-Object { $_-match $SerchText}  | ForEach-Object {
                $_-split ' ' | Select-Object -Last 1
            }
        }
    }
    
    $PathArray = $doc.FullName
    #Launch Excel
    #Find first blank row #, and activate the first cell in that row
    $FirstBlankRow = $($xl.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows)[-1].Row + 1
    $XL.ActiveSheet.Range("A$FirstBlankRow").Activate()
    #Create PSObject with the properties that we want, convert it to a tab delimited CSV, and copy it to the clipboard
    $Record = [PSCustomObject]@{
        'ID' = $PathArray
        'Context' = $CVSInfo
    }
    $Record | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | Clip
    #Paste at the currently active cell
    $XL.ActiveSheet.Paste() | Out-Null
    # Save and close
    $WB.Save() | Out-Null
    
}
$WB.Close() | Out-Null
$XL.Quit() | Out-Null
#Release ComObject
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($XL)
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As @zdan says: close the document.  Also, why create multiple instances of Excel? Create the entire CSV, then at the end push to Excel. Copy/Paste is also rather crude. What I would do is populate a an array of PSCustomObject then serialize it to Excel using [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have hundreds of Word documents open. Don't forget to close them in each iteration of the loop:

```
$Document.Close()
```